# SSL for a subdomain affect on root domain security

Tags: ssl, heroku, stripe-payments, web-hosting, firebase-hosting

I have a webapp hosted on firebase hosting at example.com. Firebase provisions a SSL for the root domain. I now connected a ghost blog hosted on heroku at subdomain blog.example.com. I do process credit card payments through my webapp (root domain). Now I am unclear if i should purchase a SSL certificate from third party and provision it with my subdomain(blog.example.com). Is it required for my blog? can it affect my root domain security? WOuld a free SSL from something like Let's encrypt me enough for the blog subdomain .

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that: No, your blog being unsecured won't affect your webapp's HTTPS security on the root domain (actually called the "apex domain", although usually www.example.com is also made to work the same as the apex domain in web browsers).

When someone visits your secure webapp via the domain example.com, the webapp will present to the client a certificate that is only valid for example.com (and maybe some/all subdomains) that was signed by a certificate authority that most clients keep in their root trust store. This verifies to a decent degree of certainty that the page they are loading is actually from the person/organization that owns the example.com domain. The client/server then do a key exchange and then start enciphering the acutal payload of the HTTP session. This ensures data between the client/server hasn't been modified, and the connection cannot be eavesdropped upon.

You can run other services at blog.example.com or somethingelse.example.com and that wouldn't affect security for users going to example.com.

The plausible reason that you might want to use HTTPS on your blog is if your blog contains links to point users towards your secure site, and you want to make sure users always get directed from those links appropriately. Since your blog is unsecured, anyone with a *privileged network position* can modify how your blog looks to someone that loads it. State or ISP actors could modify how your blog looks almost anywhere, but even a simpler example of a malicious user at a coffee shop can affect how other browsers at the coffee shop load unsecured sites virtually undetectably. Imagine if your blog contains a link "click here to go to my main site and give me money" but the link was modified to go to a phishing site to allow the attacker to steal users' passwords and/or money.

Only you can decide if this means your blog should have security. While setting up HTTPS can be more work, encrypting everything by default certainly can only help, and many people have undertaken this mantra in the past few years. Certainly Let's Encrypt would be good enough for this.